# Java SSL handshake failure in Linux but not in OSX and Windows

Tags: java, linux, ssl

I'm trying to access a webservice via axis and I'm getting a weird error in my production server (running Oracle Java 1.7.0_51). The error is `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake`. So I created a simple java application to test the SSL connection to the server I'm trying to access:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

import org.jsslutils.sslcontext.X509SSLContextFactory;

public class SSLTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")
                + "/store.p12"), "pwd".toCharArray());
        X509SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = new X509SSLContextFactory(ks,
                "pwd", null);
        SSLContext sc = sslContextFactory.buildSSLContext("TLS");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(
                "https://producao.ginfes.com.br/")).openConnection();
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        print_https_cert(con);
    }

    private static void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con) {

        if (con != null) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
                System.out.println("\n");

                Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
                for (Certificate cert : certs) {
                    System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
                    System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }

            } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I run this program in my OSX dev box (with Oracle Java 1.7.0_51) or in my Windows virtual machine (same Java version) it goes through the SSL handshake as expected. However, I tried running this code in 2 different Linux machines (one running Debian and one running Ubuntu) and I got the SSL handshake error. I tried copying my cacerts from OSX to Linux but the result was the same. Here's the very end of the SSL debug log (what happens before this is pretty standard and seems to be fine):

```
*** CertificateVerify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 101, 104, 63, 185, 83, 175, 198, 66, 90, 163, 8, 111 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
```

I also noticed that the program takes a little longer to run when the error happens (about 10s). Any ideas?

**Update**: I tried to run the program above on OpenJDK 1.6.0_18 on the ubuntu box and the result was the same. I also tried running the same code on a Debian virtual machine and it worked.

**Update**: I added the debug level and compared the logs between a machine that's working and one that is not.

Working machine:

```
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C 5C A9 32 C7   47 B7 B1 83 96 47 D8 D1  ....\.2.G....G..
0010: 9B BD 15 31 51 2E 45 65   81 2B 1B 26 08 08 8D 1A  ...1Q.Ee.+.&....
0020: E2 85 A5 2A 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  ...*............
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 16 03 01 00 30 DB 48 03   85 60 A8 B9 42 0F C6 40  ....0.H..`..B..@
0010: 91 F0 E5 50 1F 41 92 79   5F FE 31 B0 D5 BC D6 61  ...P.A.y_.1....a
0020: C0 50 D6 BB 3D 97 21 A6   ED 50 C1 96 0C 17 BE 41  .P..=.!..P.....A
0030: A8 13 C7 63 C3                                     ...c.
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 01 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 30                                     ....0
[Raw read]: length = 48
```

Non-working machine:

```
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C C0 77 AD 05   06 CD 4B 55 19 25 22 1E  .....w....KU.%".
0010: 92 2E 87 6D CD 38 06 4E   D2 33 4D 27 4B 2A 05 2B  ...m.8.N.3M'K*.+
0020: DF C2 D1 47 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  ...G............
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 16 03 01 00 30 31 5B 38   C5 0D 02 34 A4 8D BB 2D  ....01[8...4...-
0010: 2E A0 96 8E E0 D4 33 43   27 3F DE FB 2D 53 A4 83  ......3C'?..-S..
0020: 67 73 12 C5 A3 61 0C C1   EA C4 AF 0F 1B 44 5F 7B  gs...a.......D_.
0030: B2 21 4D 51 2D                                     .!MQ-

***** It stops here for about 10s *****

[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 01 00                                              ..
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
```

I guess the main difference is that I get `15 03 01 00 02` in the problematic machines and `14 03 01 00 01` in the working ones.

Here's a more complete debug log for the handshake on the problematic machine:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<CN=AC SINCOR RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PF v1, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC VALID RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign G3, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SOLUTI, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Certificadora Digital v1, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign Multipla G5, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Instituto Fenacon RFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC BR RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PJ-1 v1, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Presidencia da Republica v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SOLUTI Multipla, OU=AC SOLUTI, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEST RFB v2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign-JUS G3, OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica - AC-JUS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SINCOR RFB G4, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Autoridade Certificadora Principal v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC OAB, OU=ORDEM DOS ADVOGADOS DO BRASIL CONSELHO FEDERAL, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Imprensa Oficial G3, OU=Imprensa Oficial do Estado S A IMESP, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Certificadora Digital v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEMGE G2, OU=Companhia de Tecnologia da Informacao do Estado de MG - PRODEMGE, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEMGE RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEST RFB V1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign Multipla G3, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Autoridade Certificadora Principal v1, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Notarial RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SERASA RFB v1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Instituto Fenacon, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC VALID, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora do PRODERJ v2, OU=Servico Federal de Processamento de Dados - SERPRO, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA-JUS v1, OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica - AC-JUS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA v1, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v1, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SINCOR G3, OU=SINCOR-SP - Sindicato dos Corretores de Seguros no Estado de SP, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Casa da Moeda do Brasil, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil v3, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign SPB G5, OU=CSPB-2, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Imprensa Oficial G2, OU=Imprensa Oficial do Estado S A IMESP, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEMGE RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC FENACON Certisign RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Notarial RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign G5, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC OAB G2, OU=ORDEM DOS ADVOGADOS DO BRASIL CONSELHO FEDERAL, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v1, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC BR RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC FENACON Certisign RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SINCOR G2, OU=SINCOR-SP - Sindicato dos Corretores de Seguros no Estado de SP, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PF v2, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v2, OU=CSPB-1, OU=Servico Federal de Processamento de Dados - SERPRO, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SERASA-JUS v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica - AC-JUS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Casa da Moeda do Brasil v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v3, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Presidencia da Republica v3, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Imprensa Oficial SP RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Imprensa Oficial SP RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SERPRO-JUS v4, OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica - AC-JUS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRORFB, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PETROBRAS G3, OU=PETROLEO BRASILEIRO S A PETROBRAS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica v3, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PJ v2, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Autoridade Certificadora v2, OU=CSPB-4, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PJ v1, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC FENACOR v1, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC VALID BRASIL, OU=Autoridade Certificadora VALID - AC VALID, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Instituto Fenacon G2, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA-JUS v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica - AC-JUS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SERASA RFB v2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC SINCOR RFB G3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign G6, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign SPB G3, OU=CSPB-2, OU=Certisign Certificadora Digital S.A., O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Instituto Fenacon RFB G2, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PRODEMGE G3, OU=Companhia de Tecnologia da Informacao do Estado de MG - PRODEMGE, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Imprensa Oficial SP G3, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora SERPRORFB v3, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC CAIXA PF-1 v1, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Justica v4, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC Certisign RFB G4, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v3, OU=CSPB-1, OU=Servico Federal de Processamento de Dados - SERPRO, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=SERASA Autoridade Certificadora v1, OU=CSPB-4, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
<CN=AC PETROBRAS G2, OU=PETROLEO BRASILEIRO S A PETROBRAS, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR>
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: reck
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=RECK ADUANEIRA DA AMAZONIA LTDA EPP:04196535000130, OU=Autenticado por Certisign Certificadora Digital, OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, L=Manaus, ST=AM, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 24264184986868774817109830233364138275159044314776683839159346319997124349933949877714767467019900893922103704627632635801354814980174333627259816789227876034401362981372036626722143197822471256073667985551606390419290945624717517336706723117075591357700922888857619015416854504245521884304442214801958124913868169748389485419085887733283148575345306707962145302335042268398018623594061588310268698492035969886039355083147115598208957166248264558044010787457176664927563276373784025971208332280527156543734405427875599738053187830200999849548622241460736320436233846016936389807957942162381899068664985384000873470187
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Feb 24 20:00:00 AMT 2014,
               To: Tue Feb 24 19:59:59 AMT 2015]
  Issuer: CN=AC Certisign RFB G4, OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
  SerialNumber: [    7fba6035 25b2378c abca9da3 6e5a5932]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://icp-brasil.certisign.com.br/repositorio/certificados/AC_Certisign_RFB_G4.p7c
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.certisign.com.br
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 2E 91 EA D6 6D E5 B2 59   82 DC 38 85 29 76 34 16  ....m..Y..8.)v4.
0010: 56 3C D0 3E                                        V<.>
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://icp-brasil.certisign.com.br/repositorio/lcr/ACCertisignRFBG4/LatestCRL.crl]
, DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://icp-brasil.outralcr.com.br/repositorio/lcr/ACCertisignRFBG4/LatestCRL.crl]
, DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://repositorio.icpbrasil.gov.br/lcr/Certisign/ACCertisignRFBG4/LatestCRL.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.76.1.2.1.12]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 5C 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 69 63 70 2D 62 72 61  .\http://icp-bra
0010: 73 69 6C 2E 63 65 72 74   69 73 69 67 6E 2E 63 6F  sil.certisign.co
0020: 6D 2E 62 72 2F 72 65 70   6F 73 69 74 6F 72 69 6F  m.br/repositorio
0030: 2F 64 70 63 2F 41 43 5F   43 65 72 74 69 73 69 67  /dpc/AC_Certisig
0040: 6E 5F 52 46 42 2F 44 50   43 5F 41 43 5F 43 65 72  n_RFB/DPC_AC_Cer
0050: 74 69 73 69 67 6E 5F 52   46 42 2E 70 64 66        tisign_RFB.pdf

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
  emailProtection
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  Other-Name: Unrecognized ObjectIdentifier: 2.16.76.1.3.4
  Other-Name: Unrecognized ObjectIdentifier: 2.16.76.1.3.2
  Other-Name: Unrecognized ObjectIdentifier: 2.16.76.1.3.3
  Other-Name: Unrecognized ObjectIdentifier: 2.16.76.1.3.7
  RFC822Name: raraujo@reckaduaneira.com.br
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 9E E2 B9 4D DC B5 86 67   36 2E 08 30 66 43 2A EB  ...M...g6..0fC*.
0010: C6 BA 45 5F BF 5D 9D 9E   B0 FD 20 50 75 12 C2 4E  ..E_.].... Pu..N
0020: D1 FC 46 2C 33 DB 04 31   B9 1C 6F C1 53 DE 58 F6  ..F,3..1..o.S.X.
0030: F7 BF A8 D8 E3 DD 88 05   4B 8B 7A 37 8F 92 C6 47  ........K.z7...G
0040: 40 AE 7F 95 32 FD 82 0C   4E 10 73 A2 21 D8 BF F0  @...2...N.s.!...
0050: 0A EC 1D 14 96 32 98 78   00 18 16 62 EA 3E 99 8F  .....2.x...b.>..
0060: 6F 55 71 63 A0 72 81 AE   EC F7 19 70 4B 36 4C B4  oUqc.r.....pK6L.
0070: 2B 76 7B 95 36 BA DA CA   38 B7 EE 8F F2 C8 76 AE  +v..6...8.....v.
0080: 47 F9 D0 C0 DB 2F 0A 21   F1 25 83 E8 E5 72 A9 7D  G..../.!.%...r..
0090: 4C C7 6A F8 7D D7 7D C8   D5 7F 67 E8 F8 A2 9D 75  L.j.......g....u
00A0: D0 69 8F 44 CF 04 DA 8D   77 A6 75 BD 7E 83 4C FB  .i.D....w.u...L.
00B0: E6 8C D9 79 12 3B A6 5E   A6 56 1F C8 E6 99 75 DE  ...y.;.^.V....u.
00C0: 93 3B 96 6C 87 A9 EF 99   8C D2 EA BD C5 24 28 86  .;.l.........$(.
00D0: 69 BD 4C 85 06 88 DE 78   06 C1 42 D0 07 1F F6 06  i.L....x..B.....
00E0: EF 32 17 49 22 B1 68 5C   80 CB 51 C4 1F F5 EB 1F  .2.I".h\..Q.....
00F0: A7 D6 A9 36 04 27 38 A4   08 97 78 80 2C 10 55 47  ...6.'8...x.,.UG
0100: C3 9B 1C 72 8F 73 56 85   30 29 82 99 E6 86 F3 09  ...r.sV.0)......
0110: 7F 3D 65 40 3F 8A BE E8   6F 12 AB FE 5C B6 9F 3F  .=e@?...o...\..?
0120: 37 7F B1 75 C0 3A 05 8D   5B 30 27 EA E7 A7 D2 4F  7..u.:..[0'....O
0130: 2D 57 1D E3 7B 8B 88 18   0A 53 26 8B AD D6 98 BB  -W.......S&.....
0140: 05 13 EE 29 0F BD 8D BC   C0 F9 40 26 28 23 D5 9F  ...)......@&(#..
0150: 1B 01 3A 8A 6E 6D 07 8A   73 78 75 84 10 30 C9 E9  ..:.nm..sxu..0..
0160: 87 DC 62 C8 43 60 95 ED   42 FB 72 3F E0 F1 0E 03  ..b.C`..B.r?....
0170: CE 61 69 EC 74 E2 9E E9   99 37 AA 60 29 E6 4B 7D  .ai.t....7.`).K.
0180: 68 54 8F 5F 62 33 81 98   24 FC FE 55 11 B8 D5 3F  hT._b3..$..U...?
0190: 4D DC E7 91 66 99 92 66   0E 5F D9 1A B1 79 29 8F  M...f..f._...y).
01A0: 2D 64 90 B6 65 27 B5 B7   50 90 7F 3D DD 9F 04 71  -d..e'..P..=...q
01B0: B2 62 6C 9D 1A 84 59 A3   C8 F2 E0 14 CC DB 7F 6E  .bl...Y........n
01C0: 1F CA 26 DE C6 79 DC B4   1C 11 98 27 93 02 BF 63  ..&..y.....'...c
01D0: 9F FD 64 DB D3 AB D3 71   30 44 C3 27 81 45 66 5E  ..d....q0D.'.Ef^
01E0: B1 E8 F1 31 86 57 8C 0F   56 0A F4 73 EC 92 86 6E  ...1.W..V..s...n
01F0: E8 D6 AD 7A F7 46 BF 19   57 E2 10 BB 8D 10 D9 CC  ...z.F..W.......

]
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2427
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 60 9E 6C E9 27 4A   72 09 D1 52 89 13 AE 49  ..`.l.'Jr..R...I
0010: 63 C2 E7 65 01 7E B5 D3   B3 3D 8E 26 A4 EC 4F 98  c..e.....=.&..O.
0020: DF C1 75 8B 05 87 4D 49   09 85 BD E1 11 9C 39 65  ..u...MI......9e
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 53 0F 26 B0 D4 96 D4 FF   C3 5A 90 A5 59 6D 62 92  S.&......Z..Ymb.
0010: C2 C0 6A 5B 53 8F 03 82   F6 DB DA 12 CF C4 92 74  ..j[S..........t
Server Nonce:
0000: 53 0F 26 AE 59 92 B6 3F   9B 5F 31 51 1C 6B C6 63  S.&.Y..?._1Q.k.c
0010: 4F 82 F3 6A 57 E3 76 8B   57 F4 1B 63 E3 FF DC F2  O..jW.v.W..c....
Master Secret:
0000: 73 EE 18 E9 0F 0A 05 B0   DC 88 93 B3 0D E0 C4 FE  s...............
0010: C1 D1 18 66 D7 32 7A E2   6A 7D 8B 26 77 42 10 16  ...f.2z.j..&wB..
0020: 26 94 04 B6 41 56 E0 14   DC 1C B1 99 3A 21 DB DC  &...AV......:!..
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 18 9E 28 78 D6 7D 5C 41   7D CB C6 36 1B AC D7 43  ..(x..\A...6...C
0010: 66 4D 49 74                                        fMIt
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 4F E9 4B FE 71 B0 03 7A   6E 27 34 4E 25 23 54 90  O.K.q..zn'4N%#T.
0010: 7A 09 D2 90                                        z...
Client write key:
0000: 36 68 CF 35 5D ED 5F 47   0B 3A 4A 7B 39 03 6C E4  6h.5]._G.:J.9.l.
Server write key:
0000: 8D 1C F6 9B A6 67 4A F6   9C 11 25 71 C1 CD D7 18  .....gJ...%q....
Client write IV:
0000: 39 D4 9B 42 92 E4 FD AA   10 82 3D 53 F1 55 14 DC  9..B......=S.U..
Server write IV:
0000: 59 75 C5 B2 AC F1 D6 BD   27 EF 95 2F B5 99 11 48  Yu......'../...H
*** CertificateVerify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 88, 21, 98, 75, 128, 1, 201, 112, 209, 181, 184, 61 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
```

**Update**: I mentioned before the program worked on a Debian virtual machine. It turns out that depends. If the virtual machine's network adapter is set to NAT (through my OSX dev box), it works indeed. However, if I set the network adapter to bridged and pick up a regular IP in my network, it doesn't work; it gives me the same close_notify error as my production box.

**Yet another update**: I logged in one of the problematic machines and set up a reverse ssh tunnel to my box that points to the address in question. Then, I ran the sample program pointing to localhost (instead of the direct address) so that the request gets tunneled to my dev box, who delivers it to the appropriate server. And guess what? It worked. My problem isn't solved though as this is clearly not an appropriate solution.

Comment: `15 03 01 00 02 01 00` is `close_notify.` You need to post more of the SSL log, say starting from the `CertificateRequest.`

Comment: @EJP I just updated my question with a more complete version of the handshake log as you requested. Thanks for the help

Comment: @EJP Also, see my last update. That was pretty odd.

Comment: It is. I can't explain it. You are sending a certificate on request, which was my main concern. It seems the server has extra pickiness somehow. Is the server Java? And if so can you run it with the SSL logging enabled? And post the relevant bit here? If not,can you check its logs for SSL messages?

Comment: @EJP I've isolated Java from the issue altogether. I'm reproducing the problem with wget and openssl now. Also, I don't have control over the server, I think it's IIS though. Given the nature of the question, it's more appropriate to create another one on serverfault. If it gets answered over there, I will post the answer here as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server didn't like the certificate you sent. You need to copy the *keystore* from the working platform to the non-working platform.

I would need to see more of the SSL dump starting from say the `CerticateRequest` message to assist further.

Comment: I'm using the same keystore on both machines. I actually copied the keystore file from the working platform to the non-working one.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about the keystore not the truststore.

Comment: I copied the keystore, which contains only one certificate.

Comment: OK well I can't assist further without more of the SSL log.

Comment: It had nothing to do with java and everything to do with my network. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem had nothing to do with Java and everything to do with the cable modem my ISP provided me with. My network setup is as follows:

- TP-Link TL-ER5120 serves as gateway and firewall (and link load balancer)
- Two internet links server by equal Thomson DWG874B cable modems
- One internet link served by a TL-MR3020 connected to a 3G USB modem

The 3G modem is a failover measure, really. If I routed the server traffic through the 3G modem the SSL connection would work. So the problem was either with the cable modems or the ISP itself. I use the same ISP at home (with a different cable modem) and the connection worked. So I pinned it down to the cable modem.

That cable modem is actually a wireless router as well (although wireless is disabled). The modem has a DCHP server that assigns my firewall a local IP. So my actual local network is something like 192.168.0.x, there was another network between my firewall and the cable modem,  let's say 192.168.1.x, and the cable modem had a public IP address. I never really liked this setup, but it didn't seem to cause any harm so I lived with it.

The cable modem has a setting that makes it behave as a pure cable modem and assigns whatever is connecting to it the public IP from the ISP. The setting is called switch mode, as shown below (the previous setting was Legacy RG IPv4 Mode).

[image: Thomson configuration page]

As soon as I used that, my SSL connections to that specific website started working again from Linux. I have no clue of what was going on, but I am glad it's fixed.